# Why does typeof only sometimes throw ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, expression, language-lawyer, typeof, referenceerror

In Chrome and Firefox,

```
typeof foo
```

evalulates to `'undefined'`.

But

```
typeof (function() { return foo; })()
```

throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

**This destroys the notions that I have of susbstitutability of expressions!** Until now, I knew of no conditions for which `foo` and `(function() { return foo; })()` are not the same.

Is this standard behavior? If so, it would be helpful to quote the relevant part of the ECMAScript standard.

---

EDIT:

Another example:

```
typeof (foo)
typeof (foo + 0)
```

I would have expect `(foo)` and `(foo + 0)` to throw an error.

But the first one has no error; the second one does.

Comment: I'm not sure why `typeof foo` isn't throwing the `ReferenceError`, but the function expression is probably throwing the error on the `return` statement, not on `typeof`.

Comment: Agreed. You're attempting to return something that's undefined, and your code is throwing an exception there. `(function(){ return typeof foo; })()` works as you think it would.

Comment: @ajp15243, correct. But just as `typeof (1 + 1)` first evaluates `1 + 1`, I would think that the expression `foo` is evaluated, e.g. to `2` or `'hello world'`, and that evaluation would have also throw a `ReferenceError`. Of course, that's not what happened.

Comment: Your anonymous function executes first, throwing an exception. The same thing happens when you attempt to evaluate any other undefined expression: `typeof (1 + foobar) // => ReferenceError`

Comment: @ajp15243 I understand what he's saying; if you think about how the language is evaluated, you would have to evaluate `foo` before evaluating `typeof`. That is, for example, if you say `alert("test")`, the expression `"test"` is evaluated before the `alert` is called, and should be evaluated independently of alert i.e. `alert("test")` and `someOtherFunction("test")` should not affect the value of the constant `"test"`. If that is true, why does `typeof` not evaluate `foo` independently of context?

Comment: I think the issue is your self-executing anonymous function and `typeof (foo + 0)` force evaluation whereas `typeof foo` and `typeof (foo)` do not. `typeof` by definition does not evaluate its operand, but it seems like the operand can evaluate itself.

Comment: So, @ajm, if I understand you, `typeof` is unlike every other JS operator and function in its evaluation of the operator?

Comment: Check my answer out below. Basically, `typeof` short-circuits when encountering an "unsolveable reference" returning the string "undefined".

Comment: _“This destroys the notions that I have of susbstitutability of expressions”_ — For me, `async () => await x` vs. `async () => () => await x` destroyed it. (Or similarly `(function*(){ yield x; })` vs. `(function*(){ () => yield x; })`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Basically, the [`typeof`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) operator checks whether a variable¹ is unresolvable and returns `"undefined"`. That is, `typeof` returns a defined value for undeclared variables¹ before reaching the [`GetValue`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) algorithm which throws for undeclared variables¹.

Quoting [ECMAScript 5.1 § 11.4.3 The typeof Operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) (emphasis added):

> ### 11.4.3 The typeof Operator
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* : `typeof` *UnaryExpression* is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *val* be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. If [Type](http://es5.github.io/#Type)(*val*) is [Reference](http://es5.github.io/#x8.10), then
>
>    **2.1. If [IsUnresolvableReference](http://es5.github.io/#IsUnresolvableReference)(*val*) is `true`, return `"undefined"`.**
>
>    2.2 Let val be [GetValue](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1)(*val*).
> 3. Return a String determined by [Type](http://es5.github.io/#Type)(*val*) according to [Table 20](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3).

In the other hand, the [return statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.9) -- like most operators and statements which read the value from identifier(s) -- will always call [`GetValue`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) which throws on unresolvable identifiers (undeclared variables). Quoting [ECMAScript 5.1 § 8.7.1 GetValue (V)](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) (emphasis added):

> ### 8.7.1 GetValue (V)
>
> 1. If [Type](http://es5.github.io/#Type)(V) is not Reference, return V.
> 2. Let base be the result of calling [GetBase](http://es5.github.io/#GetBase)(V).
> 3. **If [IsUnresolvableReference](http://es5.github.io/#IsUnresolvableReference)(V), throw a `ReferenceError` exception.**

Now, analyzing the code:

```
typeof (function() { return foo; })()
```

This code will instantiate a function object, execute it and only then `typeof` will operate on the function's return value (function call takes [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) over the `typeof` operator).

Hence, the code throws while evaluating the IIFE's `return` statement, before the `typeof` operation can be evaluated.

A similar but simpler example:

```
typeof (foo+1)
```

The addition is evaluated before `typeof`. This will throw an error when the [Addition Operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) calls `GetValue` on `foo`, before `typeof` comes into play.

Now:

```
typeof (foo)
```

Does not throw an error as the [grouping operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.6) (parentheses) does not "evaluate" anything per se, it just forces precedence. More specifically, the grouping operator does not call `GetValue`. In the example above it returns an (unresolvable) *Reference*.

The [annotated ES5.1 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.6) even adds a note about this:

> **NOTE** This algorithm does not apply [`GetValue`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) to the result of evaluating Expression. The principal motivation for this is so that operators such as `delete` and `typeof` may be applied to parenthesised expressions.

---

**N.B.** I've wrote this answer with the focus on providing a simple and understandable explanation, keeping the technical jargon to a minimum while still being sufficiently clear and providing the requested ECMAScript standard references, which I hope to be a helpful resource to developers who struggle with understanding the `typeof` operator.

¹ The term "variable" is used for ease of understanding. A more correct term would be *identifier*, which can be introduced into a [Lexical Environment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2) not only through variable declarations, but also function declarations, formal parameters, calling a function (`arguments`), `with`/`catch` blocks, assigning a property to the global object, `let` and `const` statements (ES6), and possibly a few other ways.

Comment: Oh great, spend several minutes of my life writing an answer so an anon downvoter can just dv it right off without reading.

Comment: Fabcricio, I have no idea why your answer was downvoted. :( Seems great.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yeah... this is probably the best answer so far IMHO

Comment: @PaulDraper thank you, no problem. I've upvoted @ RobG's answer for explaining most of this before me as well.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this standard behavior?

Yes. *typeof* doesn't throw an error because it just returns a value [as specified](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3). However, as other answers have said, the code fails when evaluating the operand.

> If so, it would be helpful to quote the relevant part of the ECMAScript standard.

When evaluating the function expression, an attempt to resolve the value of *foo* (so that it can be returned) will call the internal [*GetValue*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) method with argument *foo*. However, since *foo* hasn't been declared or otherwise created, a reference error is thrown.

#### Edit

In the case of:

```
typeof (foo)
```

"(" and ")" are [*punctuators*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.7), denoting a grouping, such as a (possibly empty) parameter list when calling a function like `foo(a, b)`, or an expression to be evaluated, e.g. `if (x < 0)` and so on.

In the case of `typeof (foo)` they simply denote evaluating *foo* before applying the typeof operator. So *foo*, being a valid identifier, is passed to *typeof*, per link above, which attempts to resolve it, can't, determines it's an *unresolveable reference*, and returns the string `"undefined"`.

In the case of:

```
typeof (foo + 0)
```

the brackets cause the expression `foo + 0` to be evaluated first. When getting the value of *foo*, a reference error is thrown so *typeof* doesn't get to operate. Note that without the brackets:

```
typeof foo + 0 // undefined0
```

because of operator precedence: `typeof foo` returns the string `"undefined"`, so `+` becomes [*addition operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) because one of the arguments is a string, it does concatenation (the string version of addition, not the mathematic version), so `0` is converted to the string `"0"` and concatenated to `"undefined"`, resutling in the string `"undefined0"`.

So any time the evaluation of an expression with an unresolveable reference is attempted (e.g. an undeclared or initialised variable) a reference error will be thrown, e.g.

```
typeof !foo
```

throws a reference error too because in order to work out what to pass to *typeof*, the expression must be evaluated. To apply the `!` operator, the value of *foo* must be obtained and in attempting that, a reference error is thrown.

Comment: Does this also explain why `typeof (foo)` does not throw an error?

Comment: @PaulDraper AFAIK the grouping operator (parentheses) only force precedence, they don't "evaluate" anything.

Answer (score 2):

The error "ReferenceError: foo is not defined" is not being thrown by `typeof`, its being thrown by the function itself. If you had used:

```
typeof (function() { return 2; })()
```

it would have returned "number" as expected, but in this example JavaScript is not even getting to the point where `typeof` is being run on anything. You are receiving the same error as if you had run:

```
function test () {
    return foo;
}
test();
```

Answer (score 2):

Digging through the spec, I think this all comes down to *when the operator in question attempts to run `GetValue()` on its operand.*

[`typeof` attempts to determine its operand's `Type` first. If that type is a `Reference` and is `IsUnresolvableReference()`, then it bails out and returns `undefined`.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) In essence, it does not fully evaluate the operand; if it did, anything that was `undefined` would throw an exception, so instead it short circuits and returns a nice, useful string.

In the examples, self-executing functions and the addition operator call `GetValue` *without* first checking for `IsUnresolvableReference()` like `typeof` does: [they call `GetValue` and throw an exception](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) if the reference is unresolved (`foo` is `undefined` in our case). (I think! This is my best guess from reading through the spec.)

Comment: What's up with the downvote fairies today? This is pretty accurate. +1

Comment: Note though that `undefined` is a bit ambiguous -- e.g. `var foo;` means `foo` is declared but has the primitive value `undefined`. I believe "undeclared" or "unresolvable" are less ambiguous for what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior. The `typeof` operator almost takes a reference of the next variable you pass to it.

So let's try `typeof foo`.

The javascript interpreter looks at typeof and finds the type of `foo`.

Now we try `typeof (function() { return foo })()`

The javascript interpreter looks at typeof. Since the expression afterwards isn't a variable, it evaluates the expression. `(function() { return foo })()` throws a `ReferenceError` because `foo` is undefined. If it were possible to pass the reference of a varialbe i.e. something like `(function() { return *foo })()` then this wouldn't happen.

Note: According to this, one may think that `typeof (foo)` would throw an error, since `(foo)` isn't a variable and must be evaluated, but that is incorrect; `typeof (foo)` will also return "undefined" if foo isn't defined.

Essentially, the interpreter evaluates the next variable, but not expression, in a "safe" context so that `typeof` doesn't throw an error.

It is a bit confusing.

Comment: I am not understanding why `typeof (foo)` does not throw an error.

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes, that is confusing, as I said. I believe it might be because `(foo)` is evaluated as a variable as well, so it runs in the "safe" non-error context. However, normal non-variable expressions do not run in that context.

Comment: So, which ones are "safe" and which are not?

Comment: I believe `foo` and `(foo)` are the only "safe" ones. Even expressions like `false || foo` or `(0, foo)` throw an error. (The comma operator returns the last value)