# Evaluating undefined JS variable returns error

Tags: javascript

So, this is apparently not allowed in Javascript today?

```
<script>
    if (fbq == null) { 
        fbq('track', 'ViewContent'); 
    }
</script>
```

Console returns this:
[image: uncaught reference error]
And also this in the web inspector:
[image: more detail]

I thought this was pretty standard code? Surely?

Ignore the fact that fbq is undefined when called on line 142. It doesn't even get there. The error happens on line 141. I've tried testing for "typeof fbq" etc, and always returns the undefined error. Bizarre.

Comment: No, you can't use names that aren't declared. That's not new. You can test for object properties like `window.fbq`.

Comment: Have You defined it ? like this `var fbq = "";`

Comment: The necessity of checking if a variable was ever declared seems like a code smell, although not sure if this was practical or just experimental.

Comment: @MarkMeyer what? You're saying " if (someUndeclaredVariable) {} " is not permitted?

Comment: Correct @3Dom, that's a `ReferenceError`

Comment: It throws a ReferenceError and always has. You can catch that error, so "not permitted" might be a bit too strong.

Comment: In 6+ years I've never encountered this issue.

Comment: That's not so surprising @3Dom you generally know the names of variable you're using. If they're being passed in a function this isn't a problem because the function parameters are declared even if undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
typeof fbq || fbq === null // undefined
```

> The typeof operator, unlike the other operators, doesn't throw a ReferenceError exception when used with an undeclared variable.

Comment: Filed under TIL. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone interested in some additional info: *"`typeof` returns a defined value for undeclared variables, before reaching the  `GetValue` algorithm which throws for undeclared variables."* - This is an [oldie but goodie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24150982/2026606), and though it's dated, I believe all said in the answer still rings true these days.

Answer (score 0):

I swear I was trying permutations of this earlier and it was also throwing the same error, but isn't now? Weird stuff going on in my browser for the last hour. Very frustrating, but this works:

```
<script>
    if (!(typeof fbq || fbq === null)) { 
        fbq('track', 'ViewContent'); 
    }
</script>
```

Just updated the script to use Sanjay's code instead of mine (which also worked).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (typeof(fbq) =='undefined' || fbq == null) { 
        fbq('track', 'ViewContent'); 
    }
```

As mentioned by @sanjay typeof operator doesn't throw ReferenceError exception when used on undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

From Mozilla:

> The value null is written with a literal: null. null is not an
>   identifier for a property of the global object, like undefined can be.
>   Instead, null expresses a lack of identification, indicating that a
>   variable points to no object. In APIs, null is often retrieved in a
>   place where an object can be expected but no object is relevant.

```
// foo does not exist. It is not defined and has never been initialized:
foo;
"ReferenceError: foo is not defined"

// foo is known to exist now but it has no type or value:
var foo = null; 
foo;
"null"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

I believe that's how it behaves. If you have a look at the spec, it says:

> 7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> ```
> If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> Return false.
> ```

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison

So basically if you try something like:

```
undefined == null // this should return true.
```

But you cannot use a reference which you have not defined. In my opinion, a good test to see if the variable is defined is to do something like below.

```
typeof variable !== 'undefined'
```

Feel free to ask if you need further clarifications :)