# Why does typeof within eval() throw an error in my function?

Tags: javascript, eval

I was trying to implement a function similar to [`angular.isDefined(...)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined)

but allowing to check variables and their properties, so I wrote this proof of concept:

```js
function check(s) {
  let parts = s.split('\.');
  let partial = '';

  return parts.every(p => { 
    partial += (partial ? '.': '') + p;
    let expr = `typeof ${partial}`;
    console.log('Evaluating', expr);
    return eval(expr) !== 'undefined';
  });
}

check('obj');
let obj={};
check('obj');
obj.a=1;
check('obj.a');
```

I know that `typeof` allows a non declared identifier, and it seems to work properly within `eval()`:

```js
console.log(typeof someVariableWhichDoesNotExists)
console.log(eval('typeof someVariableWhichDoesNotExists'));
```

But in my code fails when it is processed by `eval()`. What am I missing?

PS: I've read [Why does typeof only sometimes throw ReferenceError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150713/why-does-typeof-only-sometimes-throw-referenceerror) but I think it is not the same scenario, I am not checking an expression here, but just a identifier.

Comment: This is really interesting. Here's a smaller repro: `eval('typeof obj'); let obj;`. This throws a ReferenceError, but if you remove the `let obj`, the error goes away and the `eval` returns `'undefined'` as expected. Moving `let obj` before `eval` also makes the error go away, which makes me think this has something to do with hoisting.

Comment: @JordanRunning if you change `let` to `var` the code works as expected. Quite interesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with `eval()`. Your error is caused by defining `let obj` but trying to use it before it is defined. This exception is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

> But with the addition of block-scoped let and const, using typeof on let and const variables (or using typeof on a class) in a block before they are declared will throw a ReferenceError. Block scoped variables are in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the initialization is processed, during which, it will throw an error if accessed

You can cause this error easily without `eval()`:

```js
// undefined no problem because obj was not declared
console.log(typeof obj)

// undefined but variable declared with let
// but not defined before using it results in an error
console.log(typeof otherobj)
let otherobj = {}
```

Your error goes away if you remove the `let obj={};` declaration or use `var obj = {}`.

Comment: For further info on the issue regarding `let`, the Mozilla web documentation about the [Temporal Dead Zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone) is really useful in this instance.