# Javascript typeof throws referenceerror

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, typeof, referenceerror

lets get right into it.
I am using `typeof` to check if a variable API exists.
I learned that `typeof` returns "undefined" if the variable does not exist.

```js
function exitApplication() {
    let typeOfApi = typeof API;
    if (typeOfApi !== "undefined") {
        API.close(() => {
            strip.shutdown();
            ...
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Bye!");
        process.exit(0);
    }
}
```

If I now run my program with test data that leads into a call to `exitApplication` when API is not yet defined I get a ReferenceError:

```
    let typeOfApi = typeof API;
                    ^

ReferenceError: API is not defined
```

Because I am using Webpack I changed the output file and replaced API with anything else that was not defined and voila it works and `typeOfApi` is "undefined" (the code I pasted is the Webpack outup).

API is a const value and I only use let and const in my code. I read something about Temporal Dead Zones, but typeof should still return "undefined" if a let variable is not defined?

I also read this [Why does typeof only sometimes throw ReferenceError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150713/why-does-typeof-only-sometimes-throw-referenceerror) but I am not using a expression.

Oh and my code is written in typescript. But I am not that "good" at it and don't really know how to get the types for restify, so `API` is of type `any`. (I know that typeof and the typescript type are completely different things :D). But the code seems to be translated 1 to 1 anyways.

Edit:
So I made this little example. This is the Webpack output

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./src/test.ts");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./src/test.ts":
/*!*********************!*\
  !*** ./src/test.ts ***!
  \*********************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

exitApplication();
const API = {};
function exitApplication() {
    let typeOfApi = typeof API;
    console.log(typeOfApi);
    if (typeOfApi !== "undefined") {
        console.log("Bye!");
        process.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Bye!");
        process.exit(0);
    }
}


/***/ })

/******/ });
//# sourceMappingURL=LED-Controller.js.map
```

And this will also throw a referenceerror

Edit: Here are my TS and Webpack configs.
https://gist.github.com/Lucarus/ebbfab5cc6560094a292ba86557ffd1d 
For the example I replaced Applications.ts with test.ts but it used the same config.

Comment: Have you tried just `if(API){...}`?

Comment: can you show where you have defined the API? Also why are you checking the type of an API if it is any?

Comment: @ScottMarcus API is not defined so this throws a referenceerror

Comment: I have no clue why this is happening. I've tried to reproduce the issue but couldn't. Maybe try removing bits of code until you find the minimum reproducible snippet? But the way I've dealt with checking for existence of global vars in the past is to use try/catch in a function: `const apiExists = () => { try { return !!API } catch(e) { return false } }`

Comment: If `API` isn't defined, then why would you think you could get its type?

Comment: Or you could use `if (window.API)` if this is only supposed to run in the browser.

Comment: @ScottMarcus read my question. typeof will return "undefined" if you pass it a variable that is not created. Look at the typeof documentation ;)

Comment: @suddjian seems like I will have to use that. I stripped away EVERYTHING and it does not work ^^.

Comment: Can you share your typescript and webpack config?

Comment: @suddjian I added it to my question. But do you agree that typeof should not return a ReferenceError ? and should rather return "undefined". I am not sure if it has something to do with es6 and the way let is more scope specific than var.

Comment: I understand how `typeof` works. I'm asking you why do you think you would get a valid type from `API` if you've never declared it?

Comment: @ScottMarcus the thing is I don't know if it has been declared yet. I will restructure my code anyways. But based on how typeof works it should return "undefined", try it in your node interpreter just type `typeof thisIsNotDeclared` and it will return a string "undefined". But as it seems the way es6 and let/const work, the interpreter knows that there should be an API but there is none and thus throws an error but if the interpreter knows the variable does not exist it will return "undefined". (Not 100% sure on that yet. But I think it has something to do with Temporal Dead Zone)

Comment: @ScottMarcus yep, I found that http://es-discourse.com/t/why-typeof-is-no-longer-safe/15 and that https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

typeof only works with var

Comment: It is absolutely the Temporal Dead Zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a function that references the `const API = {}` variable BEFORE that variable has been initialized, but inside the scope where it will be declared.  With `const` and `let`, that is not allowed.  You have this:

```
exitApplication();
const API = {};
function exitApplication() {
    let typeOfApi = typeof API;
    console.log(typeOfApi);
    if (typeOfApi !== "undefined") {
        console.log("Bye!");
        process.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Bye!");
        process.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The function is hoisted to the top of that scope so that's why you can call `exitApplication()`, but you have not yet executed the line of code that initializes `API`.  But, the intrepreter knows it's there and not yet initialized and it's a `ReferenceError` in Javascript to attempt to access a `const` or `let` defined variable in the scope where it is defined before it the line containing its declaration runs.

When I run this in Chrome, the exact error I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'API' before initialization
```

which is telling you exactly what the problem is.  In the first pass of the interpreter, it has parsed the code and it knows that `const API = {}` is there, so its illegal to access it until it reaches that line of code that initializes it.  If you really want to get around this, then change `const` to `var`, but there's likely just a better way to write your code that doesn't need to use `var`.

---

Of course, if you just move the declaration of `API` up one line, no problem:

```
const API = {};
exitApplication();
function exitApplication() {
    let typeOfApi = typeof API;
    console.log(typeOfApi);
    if (typeOfApi !== "undefined") {
        console.log("Bye!");
        process.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Bye!");
        process.exit(0);
    }
}
```

---

For a good article on this topic, you can read this article: [Why typeof is no longer safe](http://es-discourse.com/t/why-typeof-is-no-longer-safe/15).

Comment: Yea I get that, but shouldn't typeof catch that ? I know I had to "trick" typescript linter so that I could even compile it to js.
But the thing is, if I open node in the interpret mode where I can type code and it interprets one line after the other (Like just running the node command in terminal ^^). I can type "typeof foo" and it will return "undefined". And also if I change the variable API to anything else like foobar in my code it will work too.
var works because it creates every variable that is declared with var even thou the interpreter has not yet reached the declaration for it.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now, you mean because the Interpreter knows that there will be an API variable it will throw the reference error ?
And if I want to reference a variable that does not exist and the Interpreter doesn't know of its existence it will return "undefined" ?
Is this related to the Temporal Dead Zones and how let is handled differently to var ?
And how would you check for the existence of API, I could use a try catch, or rework my code so that it will not be called before API is defined. Thanks ;)

Comment: Could you add http://es-discourse.com/t/why-typeof-is-no-longer-safe/15 to your answer ? that made it more clear for me ^^

Comment: @Lukas - Added to my answer.