# conditional rendering of component in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I used to render a component depending on the screen width by writing something like this.

```html
function App(props) {
    const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(() => window.innerWidth < 576 ? true : false)
    return (
        <div>
            {
                mobile ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
            }
        </div >
    );
}
```

But now that I'm using Next.js this gives me several errors due to the window.innerWidth reference.
How could I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. What's the error msg ?

Comment: Might check out https://medium.com/frontend-digest/why-is-window-not-defined-in-nextjs-44daf7b4604e.

Comment: NextJS is isomorphic (runs on server & client). `window` is undefined on the server so you'll see an error. You need to do a check like `window && window.innerWidth < 576`

Comment: `window &&` will still throw server-side. `typeof` can be used to check whether variables have been declared safely, e.g. `typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.innerWidth < 576 ? true : false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a reference error because you cannot access the `window` object in `useState`. Instead, you have to set the initial value in useState to `undefined` or `null` and use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) where `window` can be referenced to call `setMobile(window.innerWidth < 576 ? true : false)`. finally, in your render method, you can check whether `mobile` state is set using `setMobile` (i.e., not `undefined` or `null`) and use the defined mobile state value (either `true` or `false`) to conditionally render your ComponentA or ComponentB. Also, you need to add `window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)` when your App component is mounted and remove it when it is unmounted, which you also do in `useEffect` since that is where you get reference to `window`. Otherwise, resizing the browser will not trigger an update to `mobile` state. Here is a working example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(undefined)

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateMobile = () => {
      setMobile(window.innerWidth < 576 ? true : false)
    }

    updateMobile()
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateMobile)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateMobile)
    }
  }, [])

  return typeof mobile !== 'undefined' ? (
    mobile ? (
      <ComponentA />
    ) : (
      <ComponentB />
    )
  ) : null
}
```

Comment: Wow! that was awesome. It works fine.
I was all day long trying with the useState, useEffect and process.browser, reading about the not window in the server side. I was getting infinite loop errors for either one or another component in the first render. The first render doesn't show the componentA nor the componentB. That was the key.
Thansk very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're seeing something along the lines of `ReferenceError: window is not defined`:

[`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) is thrown when a non-existent variable is referenced.

This is occurring because, in NextJS, components are often initially rendered server-side, using NodeJS, before being handed over for clients to consume. Additionally, in NodeJS, there is no such thing as `window` — hence, *window is not defined*.

Fortunately, `typeof` can be used in such cases to safely check variables before attempting to use them (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24150982/5566355) for additional info).

See below for a practical example.

```
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(() => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return false
  return window.innerWidth < 576
})
```